# Convert multilevel array to dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have following models: Car and CarType and I create array of cars below. I would like to convert that array of cars to dictionary [String: [Car]]

```
struct Car {
   let carId: Int
   let carName: String
   let carType: [Category]

   init(carId: Int, carName: String, carType: [Category]) {
                self.carId = carId
                self.carName = carName
                self.carType = carType
   }
}

struct Category {
   let categoryId: Int
   let categoryName: String
}

var cat1 = Category(categoryId: 123, categoryName: "Truck")
var cat2 = Category(categoryId: 123, categoryName: "Family")

let car1 = Car(carId: 1, carName: "Ford", carType: [cat1])
let car2 = Car(carId: 2, carName: "Honda", carType: [cat1, cat2])

let cars = [car1, car2]
```

I would like to convert cars array to `[String: [Car]]` dictionary.

Comment: What does `String` (the dictionary key) represent? And please avoid redundant information in the structs for example `struct Car { let id: Int; let name: String; let type: [Category] }` is sufficient according to the naming guidelines.

Comment: Thanks @vadian. String in dictionary would be carName.

Comment: But `car1` and `car2` have different names. Do you want `["Ford": [car1], "Honda": [car2]]`?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an API: [Dictionary(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init)

```
let groupedCars = Dictionary(grouping: cars, by: {$0.carName})
```